# Getting id from MySQL to modal and passing it through Ajax

Tags: php, mysql

I fetched the id from the database and passed it to the modal, and then echo it on another page through ajax but the problem is that it keeps returning the same id

```
        <?php if(mysqli_num_rows($select_invoice_query)>0) {
        while($invoice_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_invoice_query)) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td><a href="#send-invoice-modal" id="send_invoice" data-toggle="modal" data-invoiceid="<?php echo $invoice_result['order_id']; ?>" data-placement="top" title="Send"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php  }} ?>
```

Bootstrap Modal

```
         <div id="send-invoice-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Send Invoice</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
         <div class="form-group">
         <input type="email" id="invoice_to" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"> 
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
         <input type="text" id="invoice_subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject">  
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
         <textarea class="form-control" id="invoice_message" rows="3" placeholder="Message"></textarea>  
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="send_invoice_btn">Send</button>
         <div class="error_message"></div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

JS

```
   $('#send_invoice_btn').on('click',function(){
      var invoice_id = $('#send_invoice').data('invoiceid'); // this is collecting the id from the anchor tag 
      var invoice_to = $('#invoice_to').val(); 
      var invoice_subject = $('#invoice_subject').val(); 
      var invoice_message = $('#invoice_message').val(); 
   
      $.ajax({
         url: "includes/send-invoice.inc.php"+invoice_id,
         type: 'POST',
         data: {invoice_id:invoice_id,invoice_to:invoice_to,invoice_subject:invoice_subject,invoice_message:invoice_message},
         success: function(send_invoice_result){
             $('.error_message').html(send_invoice_result);
         }
      })    
   });
```

send-invoice.inc.php File

```
<?php 


include 'db-connection.php';

echo $invoice_id = $_GET['invoice_id'];


?>
```

it keeps returning the same id for some unknown reason. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like all of the anchor tags have `id="send_invoice"`, which one should it pick?

Comment: It's inside the while loop. So it would automatically echo the id for their respective invoices. I'm trying to collect the id when the user clicks on send_invoice_btn and pass it to another page but it keeps returning the same id @NigelRen

Comment: *It's inside the while loop. So it would automatically echo the id for their respective invoices* the loop is run to generate the web page, when they click on the link is totally separate.  This is something fundamental to the life cycle of a web page.

Comment: so what is the solution to this problem? Could you please enlighten me? @NigelRen

Comment: I know problem lies here var invoice_id = $('#send_invoice').data('invoiceid') because it is collecting the same id always.

Comment: I'm trying to pick up their respective invoice id (depends which anchor user clicked on) I hope you will answer my question @NigelRen

Comment: I figured it out! I answered my own question but could you please check if it is a correct way to do it @NigelRen

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
       $('.send_invoice').on('click',function(){
      var invoice_id = $(this).attr('data-invoiceid');
      
      $('#send_invoice_btn').on('click',function(){
         var invoice_to = $('#invoice_to').val();
         var invoice_subject = $('#invoice_subject').val();
         var invoice_message = $('#invoice_message').val();
          
        $.ajax({
           url: 'includes/send-invoice.inc.php?invoice_id='+invoice_id,
           type: 'POST',
           data: {invoice_to:invoice_to,invoice_subject:invoice_subject,invoice_message:invoice_message},
           success: function(send_invoice_result){
               
           }
        });
      });    
   });
```